# Getting 417 error when using webrequest

Tags: asp.net

I have a schedule task that is making a webrequest. This was all working fine. However all of sudden i'm getting the following error log.

---

12/05/2010 20:21:17
Failure reading XML
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation failed.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at DelegateImport.Update.UpdateLiveSite(String delegateId, String badgeId)
   at DelegateImport.Rss.RssReader()

Here is the code making the web request

```
                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (uri);
                   request.Method = "POST";                        
                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
                    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                    request.Timeout = 30000000;
                    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
                  dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    dataStream.Close ();
                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
                    Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
                    Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
                    reader.Close ();
                    dataStream.Close ();
                    response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, .NET will tag outgoing POST requests with the header `Expect: 100-Continue`. If the server doesn't support this, it will fail with a 417 error.

To get .NET to not do this, execute the following before creating your WebRequest object:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Comment: i've tried that like so, but no luck - 

System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (uri);

Comment: Any chance somewhere earlier in your code is talking to the same URL prior to setting this property? The ServicePointManager does reuse ServicePoints so the property needs to be set first thing (for instance, at app startup) before any requests get made.

Comment: thanks eric, i'm sure you are right. Needed a quick fix so just used "get" not ideal, but saw me through :)